# How to import "psutil"

Tags: python, psutil, juju, charm

I am trying to import and use `psutil` from within a python-script (`.py` file).

This `.py` file is part of a `juju-charm` layer. To be specific, it is a `command` script for collecting `metrics` from the machine running the `charm-application`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import psutil

if __name__ == '__main__':
  cpu_times = psutil.cpu_times(percpu=False)
  print(cpu_times )
```

Now when I build the `charm-layer` and deploy it using `juju`, I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named psutil

This means that the machine (which was brought up by `juju`) called and invoked that `.py` file successfully. But failed to import `psutil`.

My question is how to import `psutil` successfully?

(I will highly appreciate a `juju-charm` related answer if there is any but it is not necessary)

Comment: Perhaps you need to install psutil?

Comment: `psutil` does not come with standard library, you need to install it using `pip`.

Comment: sudo pip3 install psutil